# Use dynamic cell ref in a string (inside double quote "")?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Jira add-on for Google Sheets and here is an example function:

```
=JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = IAH-66", "status")
```

I'd like to replace the fixed IAH-66 issue key with a ref to a cell (in a list of issue keys) with the values (ex: IAH-67, IAH-99) so that I don't need to replace the value for every cell.

It should be something like this:

```
=JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = B2", "status")
```

But JIRA() is a query and I cannot ref to B2 cell. I tried the function below but it doesn't work:

```
=JIRA(CONCATENATE(char(34),"project = IAH and issueKey = ",AC37,char(34)), "status")
```

Is it possible?

Document link: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/use-jira-cloud-for-sheets/

Comment: Please share the desired output or sample google sheet, maybe you don't have to use an add-on and you can use `Indirect Function`

Comment: I cannot share the sample sheet since the editor will be able to access my Jira data.

I added more info.

Comment: Pls try to use this if that works - `=JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = "&B2&"&", "status")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = '"&B2&"'", "status")
```

Comment: Hello @player0, I'd like to ask how can I achieve this but with the Cell in another sheet (not the same sheet)?

Comment: Try this format:                                                                                                                                      =JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = '" & Sheet1!A3 & "'", "status")

Comment: It doesn't work if I have space in my sheet name. Ex: "Sheet 1". For the one without space, it shows: Error in the JQL Query: The character '#' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape '\u0023' instead. (line 1, character 1)

Comment: @JOY if you have spaces in sheet name use singlequote wrapping `'She et 1'!A3`