# Ref to a cell in another sheet within double quote ("")

Tags: google-sheets

Follow this question: [Use dynamic cell ref in a string (inside double quote "")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674091/use-dynamic-cell-ref-in-a-string-inside-double-quote), I'd like to achieve this but in the cells in another sheet. Is it possible?

I have tried something like =JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = '"Sheet1!&A3&"'", "status") but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close - try this version of your formula:

```
=JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = '" & Sheet1!A3 & "'", "status")
```

Let us know if it works...

If the sheet name has spaces, apply singles quotes, as follows:

```
=JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = '" & 'Sheet 1'!A3 & "'", "status")
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I have space in my sheet name. Ex: "Sheet 1".  Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G4v8YP6OFD2gun29iPysy378NmbmtM80FXlsrbK7ZXw/edit#gid=1990494946

Comment: You need to apply the basic rules of referencing sheets in Google Sheets.  Simply add singles quotes around your sheet name. eg.                                                                                =JIRA("project = IAH and issueKey = '" & 'Sheet 1'!A3 & "'", "status")